# What does "which" stand for in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Whenever I met her, ***which*** was fairly often, she greeted me with a sweet smile.

In the above sentence, *which* is a relative pronoun. I am wondering what *which* stands for. Does it stand for "I met her" or "Whenever I met her, she greeted me with a sweet smile"?

Comment: Is this your second question on the same topic? Read about how to use *non-restrictive clause* in the middle of the sentence. It'll clear most of your doubts about this topic. NRCs are used to provide some additional information and removing them will still make sense. **They refer to the clause they follow so here, it's "whenever you meet".**

Comment: quite similar - http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31272/which-as-relative-pronoun

Answer (score 1):

It stands for ***Whenever I met her***

That he met her fairly often.

Comment: You might also explain *why* it can't be either of the OP's other choices.